# Bound eigenbasis error of perturbed matrix by eigenbasis error of perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, upper-lower-bounds, perturbation-theory

I've been searching without much luck for a reference that can help with the following problem:

Let $R$, $S$, and $E$ be symmetric matrices, with $R = S + E$, where $E$ is a small perturbation. Then let $V_S$ and $V_E$ be unitary matrices diagonalizing $S$ and $E$. Can we pick a matrix $V_R$ which diagonalizes $R$ in order to get an upper bound for $||V_R - V_S||$ in terms of $||V_S - V_E||$?

Observe that in the extreme case where $V_S = V_E$, then $S$ and $E$ are simultaneously diagonalizable and we can pick $V_R = V_S$. This leads me to believe that if $V_S$ and $V_E$ are "close" we might be able to make a statement about $V_R$ and $V_S$ being "close."

Most results I've found have focused on bounding $||V_R - V_S||$ in terms of $||E||$; see Lemma 4.3 in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220179752_Strong_Semismoothness_of_Eigenvalues_of_Symmetric_Matrices_and_Its_Application_to_Inverse_Eigenvalue_Problems). Although the authors just show that $||V_R - V_S||$ is $O(||E||)$, I've been able to upper bound by a specific constant using the Davis-Kahan $\sin(\theta)$ [theorem](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Edjhsu/coms4772-f16/lectures/davis-kahan.pdf). However, I'm looking for a bound in terms of the eigenbasis misalignment $||V_S - V_E||$. Kato's *Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators* chapter 2 seemed promising, but it mainly deals with parameterizations of pertubations and doesn't look directly applicable.

Kind of at a loss for how to make progress here, any related results / references would be much appreciated!

---